# WPF markupExtension only works if it's in the same namespace

Tags: wpf

I'm following a tutorial from here: 
http://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html

### and everything works fine....Untill I devide my code in to different projects

So I have a class (TranslateExtension) that inherits from MarkupExtension. this allows me to add markup like this to WPF:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Mynamespace:Translate key1}" Margin="8" ></TextBlock>
```

and the textblock gets filled in with the necessary text

But when i want to put the front end in a different project I get the following exceptions:

- The name "Translate" does not exist in the namespace
- The type "Translate" was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built
- The tag "Translate" does not exist in XML namespace ....

I already have added a reference to the namespace on top of my XAML file and the namespace exists inside of the new project. I also have a reference from my Front end to my old project.

So everything works fine untill I extract the front end in to a different project....

IMPORTANT: If I take TranslateExtensions and Put it in the front end, with everything else in the old project, things magically work...

any ideas?

Comment: Did you correctly (re)define `xmlns:Mynamespace`? Didn't you forget to reference all the needed assemblies?

Comment: Translation and frontend should reside in the same project (that's how the .resx localization works).

Comment: thanks for your anwsers... I actually rebuild the solution to work with a database... and the database calls happen in the "data access" tier, while the front end should just use the markup. Should I work with resource files, they indeed have to be in the front end. Richards answer helped me on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML namespaces starting with `clr-namespace:` are specific to an assembly. If you don't specify the assembly name, the current assembly is assumed.

The simplest option will be to use an assembly-qualified namespace:

```
xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"
```

For a more robust solution, you might want to look at the [`XmlnsDefinitionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can be used to map multiple CLR namespaces across different assemblies to a single XML namespace URI.

Comment: this looks like a valid anwser, I'm gonna test this tomorrow and let you know.